# Angular Material Input Textbox Wrapper to work with ControlValueAccessor and inner formControlName

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to get ControlValueAccessor and formControlName working with customer Material Input Textbox.
For some reason, code is not working, and trying to fix it. Read lot of tutorials, and applying ControlValueAccsor. 
Should we use MAT_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR? What is easiest way to resolve with Material Angular?

Goal is to have this stylized textbox working with Forms.

**Typescript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, EventEmitter, Output, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-textbox',
  templateUrl: './input-textbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-textbox.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextboxComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class InputTextboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() MaxLength: string;
  @Input() Disabled: boolean;
  @Input() ReadOnly: boolean;
  @Input() NgClass:string;
  @Input() Value: string;
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() Label: string;
  @Input() PlaceHolder: string;
  @Output() saveValue = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onStateChange = new EventEmitter();

  disabled: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  saveValueAction(e) {
    this.saveValue.emit(e.target.value);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.Value = e;
  }

  onTouched() {
    this.onStateChange.emit();
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.Value = value ? value : '';
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) { this.onChange = fn; }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this.onTouched = fn; }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled) { this.disabled = isDisabled; }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-wrap">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>{{Label}}</mat-label>   
        <input matInput 
            [attr.maxlength] = "MaxLength"
            [value]="Value ? Value : ''"
            [placeholder]="PlaceHolder ? PlaceHolder : ''"
            [readonly]="ReadOnly"
            [ngClass]="NgClass"
            [type]="type ? type: 'text'"
        >
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the form group is not receiving values from the `InputTextboxComponent` is because the `onChange` method is not being called every time the `input` element receives a new value from the user. I've added an on-change event listener for the `input` element inside `InputTextboxComponent` and called the `onChange` method from there. (Line 58 of `input-text-box.component.ts`)

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4ebkp